# functions and returns

Tags: python, function, return, call

I'm new to python and I've been assigned in writing an invoice program for a hypothetical hotel. I'm running into difficulty when trying to call on functions for their return value. I could really use the help as I'm really stumped. The implementation code is to follow along with the description of the program so a handle can be put on what exactly is the mistake.

```
Invoice
```

PCCC Palace Hotel

Eddie’s Billing Statement

Number of days in hotel:  2

Room Charges    $675.00

Internet Charges    $29.85

Television Charges  $8.85

Total Charges   $703.70

Local Taxes $24.63

```
Total Due   $728.33
```

Thank you for using PCCC Palace Hotel. Hope to see you again.

Requirements:
•   Include relevant information in the form of comments in your code as explained in the class.
•   Use a different function to handle each of 
o   the room type
o   The Internet Access usage
o   The TV usage 
•   The Internet and TV usage may be denied, in that case the charges would be $0.00 
•   All the rates are defined as local constants inside the functions
•   Each function has a menu that displays the options to select from
•   Each function returns the charges incurred for that option
•   The local tax rate is 3.5% and is to be defined as a local constant

The problem is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/hotel.py", line 28, in 
    print("Room Charges: ", roomcost())
NameError: name 'roomcost' is not defined

Code:

```
def main():
input = int , 2
costofinternet = costofinternet
costoftv = costoftv


customername = input("The Customer Name Please: ")
visitdays = input("Enter the Number of Days in the Hotel: ")

room = input("Rooms Used \n1 - Single Room - One Bed \n2 - Family Room - Doulble Bed \n3 -      Suite \n Enter Choice 1, 2, or 3: ")
```

roomcost()

```
internet = input("Would You like Internet: ")
if internet == 'Y':
internettype = input("Internet Access Usage \n1 - Wireless \n2 - Wired \nEnter Choices 0, 1, or 2: ")

television = input("Would You like to use the TV: ")
if television == 'Y':
tvtype = input("TV Usage \n1 - Cable \n2 - Basic Channels \nEnter Choice 0, 1, or 2: ")

print("\t\t\t\t\t\t Invoice")
print("\t\tPCCC Palace Hotel")
print(customername, "'s Billing Statement")
print("Number of Days in Hotel: ", visitdays)
print("Room Charges: ", roomcost)
print("Internet Charges: ", costofinternet)
print("Television Charges: ", costoftv)
totalcharge = print("Total Charges: ", roomcost + costofinternet + costoftv)
localtaxes = print("Local Taxes: ", ((roomcost + costofinternet + costoftv) * .035))
print("\t\tTotal Due\t\t\t", totalcharge + localtaxes)
print("\t\tThank You For Using PCCC Palace Hotel. Hope To See You Again.")



def roomcost():
cost = []
if room == '1':
    cost == 225
if room == '2':
    cost == 325
if room == '3':
    cost == 550
return(cost)

def internet():
costofinternet = []
if internettype == '0':
    costofinternet == 0
if internettype == '1':
    costofinternet == 9.95
if internettype == '2':
    costofinternet == 5.95
return(costofinternet)

def tv():
costoftv = []
if tvtype == '0':
    costoftv == 0
if tvtype == '1':
    costoftv == 9.95
if tvtype == '2':
    costoftv == 2.95
return(costoftv)
```

Comment: You are misusing `==` and `=`. `==` checks for equality (`5==5` returns `True`) and `=` is the assignment operator (`x=5` means that `x` is now 5).

Answer (score 1):

roomcost is a function, so you'll need to call it using the () operator, along with your other function calls:

```
print("Room Charges: ", roomcost())
print("Internet Charges: ", costofinternet())
print("Television Charges: ", costoftv())
```

Comment: After implementing what you said I end up with the same exact error. May you please be more descriptive as I'm having trouble following.

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html ... You also need to make sure you're indenting the body of the functions and returning their values correctly.